# Numerical discrepancies after upgrading Fortran compilers (Intel v11.1 to v13.0)

Tags: compiler-construction, floating-point, fortran, intel

**Background:**

We're just trying to upgrade our Intel Composer installation from 2011 to 2013, but we are finding that although most results are unchanged, a few change a bit, and some quite a lot.

I've read through the release notes, and what I understood would not explain these differences (we have no multi-threading, classes - polymorphic or otherwise).

**Question:**

Are there any difference between the Intel Fortran compiler v13.0 and its immediate predecessor v11.0 in the following areas:

- Are uninitialised variables treated differently?
- Are there any compiler flags (like floating point settings) whose defaults have changed?
- Has the implicit casting of numeric types changed?

Comment: Do you have a repro case? It would help a lot if there is a specific situation where you can show a difference.

Comment: I will probably vote to close if the question is not extended: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: We do have a reproducible case, but the program is 100,000's of lines of code.  We're trying to go through line by line, but I was hoping to narrow down the areas of highest risk first.

Comment: @VladimirF : The question is fairly specific: are there any known differences between Intel Fortran compiler v13.0 and its immediate predecessor in the areas of 1) treatment of unitialised variables, 2) compile flag defaults, or 3) implicit casting.  The release notes don't mention this, but I might not expect them to mention 1), and possibly not 3).

Comment: You could always ask on the official support forum, although Steven Lionel attends this place from time to time also.

Comment: @VladimirF: I have rephrased the question such that it can be answered in three booleans - that is 12 bytes ;)

Comment: Ah, I recognise Steven Lionel's photo from every Fortran forum where an actual answer has been posted.  Yes, I suspect he's the man for this...

Comment: Your first question implies that you suspect you are referencing uninitialized variables.  That programming error absolutely can result in differences if you change compiler version.

Comment: @IanH There's obviously no uninitialised variables that we know about, but there is a lot of code and some of it dates back a long time.  The fact that the regression tests usually pass suggests there are very few if any, but a *change* in the uninitialised behaviour might reveal problems that were always there.

Comment: I see you actually posted there even before here http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/508924 I believe with this type of question the official support forum is a better place. Or even the Premier site, you are paying for it when you buy the licence and I always got a responce in a short time.

Comment: The answers to your three questions are: No, No, No. But there can be many possible causes of numerical differences, especially when the algorithm is unstable. Maybe more of the code vectorizes, improvements to math routines, different order of operations, etc., etc. As others have said, if you can provide a test case to Intel Premier Support, we'll help you figure it out. But you can also work on it by seeing where in the process the results start to diverge.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm just posting Steve Lionel's comment as an answer, so that I can close this question:

"The answers to your three questions are: No, No, No. But there can be many possible causes of numerical differences, especially when the algorithm is unstable. Maybe more of the code vectorizes, improvements to math routines, different order of operations, etc., etc. As others have said, if you can provide a test case to Intel Premier Support, we'll help you figure it out. But you can also work on it by seeing where in the process the results start to diverge." – Steve Lionel Apr 3 '14 at 20:17

Comment: Floating point math is not exactly associative, but it's very useful for optimization (especially vectorization) to pretend that it is.  Doing equivalent operations in a different order usually give very similar results.  For C compilers, you usually need to use some kind of "fast math" option to allow the compiler freedom to do this.  IDK about Fortran.